# Javascript querySelector or getElementById

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there's a difference between the 2 options, knowing all my div's are with id's?
I took them all with `querySelector`... is it better to change to `getElementById` or is it equivalent?

```
document.querySelector("#div").value;
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("div").value;
```

Comment: Better how? Performance-wise?

Comment: Or code length? That answer is easy :)

Comment: document.querySelector based ecmascript 5 standards it is works for html5 enabled browsers. but document.getElement by Id will works for legacy browsers like Internet Explorer 6.

Comment: Performance, and personal preference. I honestly think that `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` is prettier.

Comment: @sarath: IE8 doesn't support many of the HTML5 features and still supports `document.querySelector`. Just saying that it's not restricted to browser fully supporting HTML5.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/11

Comment: More about compatibility on browsers and Performance.
@NickDugger Thanks for this one. Post it as answer ;)